# dependent dropdown list is not working

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

in this code below i have a student table when i want to update i will select a drop down course_code from coursesubject table it should display corresponding subject_code from coursesubject .But my actual result is it displays all the values from coursesubject in coursecode and subject code.Pls anyone help me.

view :student_detail_view

```
<section id="tables">
<script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  oTable = jQuery('#studenttable').dataTable({
   "bJQueryUI": true,
   "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"

  });
   }); 
  </script> 
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
 function get_studentdetails() {

    var exam_name = jQuery('#exam_name_id').val();
    //alert("exam_name"+exam_name);
    jQuery.ajax({
        data: {
            exam_name: exam_name,
        },
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'student_site/studentupdate',          
        success: function(data){
        //alert("inside change");
            console.log(data);
            jQuery('#details').html(data);
            jquery('#deleting').html(data);
        }
    });
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        data: {
            exam_name: exam_name,
        },
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'student_site/studentcreate',
        success: function(data){
        //alert("inside change");
            console.log(data);
            jQuery('#crud').html(data);
            jquery('#deleting').html(data);
        }
    }); 
    });
}     

function CheckBoxVerification(From)
{
alert('hai');
    alert('hai:' $("table input[type=checkbox]:checked").length);
    if(From == "Insert")
    {
        if(!!$('#rowInsert input:checked').length == false)
        {
            alert('please select at least one check box to Create ...!');
        }
    }

    if(From == "Update")
    {
        if(!!$('#rowUpdate input:checked').length == false)
        {
            alert('please select at least one check box to Update ...!');
        }
    }
}
  function get_subjectdetails() {
    //var index = jQuery('#index').val();

    var course_name = jQuery('#course_name_id').val();
    //alert("course_name"+course_name);
    var exam_name = jQuery('#course_name_id>option:selected').text();
    var exam_name = jQuery('#exam_name_id').val();
    var ssubject_code = jQuery('#ssubject_code_id').val();
    //var partsArray = exam_name.split('.');
    //alert("ssubject_code"+ssubject_code);
    //alert("course_name"+course_name);
    //alert("exam_name"+exam_name);
    jQuery.ajax({
        data: 'exam_name='+exam_name+'&course_name=' + course_name,
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'student_site/subject_records',
        success: function(data){
        //alert("inside change");
            console.log(data);
            //alert ("data"+data);
            //for(var j = course_name; j < ssubject_code; j++)
        //{
            jQuery('#ssubject_code').empty().append(data);
        //}
        }

    });
} 

</script>

<?php 
    $attributes=array(
        'name'=>'updatecustomer',
        'id'=>'updatecustomer'
        );
    echo form_open('student_site/manage_student',$attributes);
?>
<div id="validation_failed">
    <?php
        echo validation_errors();
    ?>
    <?php $data = array();
        foreach ($course_records as $row)
        {
            $data[$row->course_code] = $row->course_code; 
        } 

        $subject_data = array();
        foreach ($all_coursesubject_records as $row)
        {
            $subject_data[$row->subject_code] = $row->subject_code; 
        }  


     ?>
     <div id="Processy">
<table class="display table table-bordered table-striped" id='studenttable'>
<thead>
<tr font style='font-size:13px'>
<th>&nbsp;</th>
<th>&nbsp;</th>
<th>Register Number</th>
<th>Name </th>
<th>Course Code</th>
<th>Subject Code</th>
</tr></thead>
<?php if(isset($records)) : foreach($records as $row) : ?>
<tr >
<td>
<?php echo anchor('student_site/delete/'.$row->id, 'Delete',array('onClick'=>"return confirm('Are you sure want to delete..?')")); ?>
</td>
<td id="rowUpdate">
<input type=checkbox name="editstudent[]" id="editstudent[]" value="<?php echo $row->id ?>">
</td>
<td ><input class="inputmedium span2" type="text" name="register_number_<?php echo $row->id ?>" id="register_number_<?php echo $row->id ?>" value="<?php echo $row->register_number; ?>" ></td>
<td ><input class="inputmedium span2" type="text" name="name_<?php echo $row->id ?>" id="name_<?php echo $row->id ?>" value="<?php echo $row->name; ?>" ></td>

<td >
<?php 

        $js = 'class="dropdown_class" id="course_code_id'.$row->id.'" onChange="get_subjectdetails()" '; 
        $js_name = 'course_code_id'.$row->id;
        echo form_dropdown($js_name, $data, $row->course_code, $js);
?>
</td>
<td>    
<?php 

        $js = 'class="dropdown_class" id="subject_code_id'.$row->id.'"'; 
        $js_name = 'subject_code_id'.$row->id;
        echo form_dropdown($js_name, $subject_data, $row->subject_code, $js);

?>
<div id="ssubject_code" ></div>
<input type="hidden" name="ssubject_code" id="ssubject_code" value="ssubject_code"/>
</td>

</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
</div>
<center>
<br /><input type="submit" class="btn-success btn" value="Update Student"></center>

<?php else : ?>
<h2>No records were returned.</h2>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dependent dropdown is not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18589612/dependent-dropdown-is-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are loading your subject along with the course, if you want to load your subject AFTER choosing course, what you can do is put your subject into a div(or tbody) tag like this

```
<div class="subject"></div>
```

and in your jquery:

```
    $("#course_code_id").live("change keypress",function(){
    var id = 0;
    id = $(this).val();
    if( $(this).val() !==''){           
        $.post('<?php echo site_url('subject/search_by_course') ?>',
            {
                subject_id: id
            },function(data){
                $(".subject").html( data['html_string']);

            },"JSON"
        );

   }
});
```

in your controller

```
function search_by_course()
{
  $this->load->model('subject_model');
  $id = $this->input->post('subject_id');

  //get your data from model
  $res_subject = $this->subject_model->subject_list($id);
  $html_string = "";
  $html_string .= "<select id='subject_code_id'>";
  for($x=0;$x<count($res_subject);$x++)
  {
     $html .= "<option id=".$res_subject[$x]->subject_id.">".$res_subject[$x]->subject_name."</option>";
  }
  $html_string .= "</select>";

  echo json_encode(array('html_string'=>$html_string));
}
```

usually, i do it like that and so far it works.